# Using server-side copy on a SMB share

Tags: samba, cp, file-copy, cifs, smb

According to the [SMB docs](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Server-Side_Copy) server-side copy should work on recent versions of SMB via `cp --reflink`

When trying this with a server running smbd 4.15 (via [crazy-max/docker-samba](https://github.com/crazy-max/docker-samba)) and a share mounted with `mount -t cifs -o uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.1.1 //host/share/ /share`, I always get `Operation not supported` for `cp --reflink /share/test /share/test2`.

The versions on the client machine are:

```
~$ mount.cifs --version
mount.cifs version: 6.9
~$ uname -r
5.4.0-125-generic
```

Why is it not working? Any ideas? Thanks!